# Dynamics 365 portals - Entity list button missing

Tags: dynamics-365, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals

I am attempting to recreate the case-list from the default /support page in Dynamics 365 portals. However, the button to the far right, that enables me to open up and view details about the case is not appearing.

[image]

From intensive research and trying, I conclude that the button is created in the "Entity list" option in portals, in the buttom menu called "Grid configuration".
[image]

However, when I create it nothing happens. As if the changes are not making it to the front. If I make the same changes to the default /support page, the changes appear instantly. I have cleared the cache, and restarted the portal.

Am I forgetting some extra setting somewhere to enable these buttons, or what am I missing? Mind that everything else on the page works 1:1 like the /support page. The individual components also work if configured with the /support page.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Entity permissions for editing your entity?

Comment: This has been double and triple checked